# What is meaning of 'sustainability is a style statement'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.pressreader.com/india/the-times-of-india-mumbai-edition/20160424/282737701016007)

I also wonder why they call 'sustainability' a 'statement.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a pretty big movement in reduce/reuse/recycle (i.e. The Green Movement) for quite some time. The article is essentially meaning that it is now fashionable to wear clothes that embrace the environment. So, clothes made from used water bottles are now becoming "in style" (popular) to wear for example. So, by wearing those clothes, you are also stating that you care about the environment.

Comment: A 'style statement' is an idiom.Right?

Comment: I don't think it is actually. Style is a synonym of fashion and you are (or could be) making a non-verbal statement by wearing it. 
You are stating that you care about the environment.

Comment: But that 'statement'?

Comment: Keep in mind that in fashion, they love to call things statements and then dream up what the statement is. It's a bold statement, or sassy, or chic, and so on.